# Color issues with 4k @ 60hz

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, 4k

I'm at my wits end on this. I've gone through two different macs and two different displays trying to fix this issue. The goal:

I want to connect my 2015 Macbook pro to a 4k Samsung display at 60hz.

I'm currently using a Mini-Displayport to Displayport adapter. If I use an HDMI cable at 30hz the picture is perfect but the picture is choppy. If I use the Mini-DP to DP adapter I get 60hz, but also really bad washed out colors and banding / dithering issues. I've tried every color profile available and none work to address this issue. The display is almost completely unusable this way and it looks like a 1990s progressive-scan LCD. At 30hz on HDMI it looks perfect.

I've googled and searched everything I know how to search.

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to get this display to work?

Comment: Which "2015 Macbook pro"? Presumably the DG, as the IG doesn't do 4k... which brings us to 2)  What size is "4k"? Also see https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.5-15-dual-graphics-mid-2015-retina-display-specs.html

Comment: AFIK without additional Graphic card you are pushing the limits

Comment: It's a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Comment: Also, I plugged back into HDMI just to look at the settings and apparently the DP connection "poisoned" my HDMI settings and now I have the same terrible color over HDMI @ 30hz too. This is clearly an issue with OSX and not a hardware problem.

Comment: Also, I tried the EDID patching, nothing worked. OSX shows the monitor as 24-Bit Color (ARGH8888)